# Deeplink to Google Map Street View but it keep spinning

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, google-street-view

I have a simple deeplink into Google Map Street View

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        findViewById<Button>(R.id.launch_street_view_button).setOnClickListener {
            val gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.streetview:cbll=46.414382,10.013988")

            val mapIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri)
            mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps")

            startActivity(mapIntent)
        }
    }
}
```

(note: the sample code of deeplink came from Google Document at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents#kotlin_16)

You can also get [the full project code here](https://github.com/VuXuanBach/SampleStreetView)

When I have an old Google Map (version 11.29.7 (#1066493137)), the deeplink into Street View works just fine as per GIF below

[image: Deeplink into Street view works]

However with the latest Google Map (version 11.57.4801 (#1066791007)), the deeplink into Street View just keep spinning forever as GIF below (for the GIF below I cut off after 10 seconds, but even if I waited for a long period, it keep spinning)

[image: Deeplink into Stret view not loading]

Is this a Google Bug? Or do we need to do something differently in our code for our Intent to get the Street View load working?

**p/s: I use the same Pixel 4 device and the same compilation of the Android Code. The only change is I**

- **update the Google Map (to version 11.57.4801) - by updating it from Google Play and**
- **downgrade the Google Map (to version 11.29.7) - by uninstalling it in Google Play.**

Comment: Have you tried adding `panoid`?  Like this `google.streetview:panoid=id&cbp=0,bearing,0,zoom,tilt`.

Comment: It tries to load and ends up stop loading the street view. It states "Street View isn't available here". This is strange, as the old Google Maps can show that well.

Comment: Looking at the first gif you provided the location seems somewhere in the mountains, maybe they changed the data. Have you used the coordinates of some common places (places that have more people)?

Comment: The sample code came exactly from Google Document https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents#kotlin_16